# Digitalocean, Wordpress and Zoho SMTP

Tags: smtp, wordpress

I have set up droplet on Digital Ocean (Ubuntu, nginx, php 5.6 and mysql) and I plan on running a Wordpress site. The site has a register/login/notification feature that will require sending out emails occasionally, max 100 emails per day.

Is it possible to use the free Zoho SMTP service for this? I know it should work in theory, I'm interested in practical experience.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a question for Zoho support. It's also very easy for you to try, just sign up for a free account and try it out.

However, yes, you can very likely use Zoho SMTP to send Wordpress emails, or any other SMTP service. Alternately AuthSMTP is a service I've used in the past. I use SSMTP to deliver email to my email server - [tutorial here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/#email).

Zoho seems to allow [200 emails](https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/zoho-mail/send-and-receive-emails.html) to be sent each day.